# Magento How to display/list all categories from catalog category flat table

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have enabled "Use Flat Catalog Category" & "Use Flat Catalog Product" to "yes" for getting better performance. But after enabling this options one of my previous cms page on which I was getting a list of all subcategories is not working anymore.
The code using which I was getting sub-categories before enabling flat data is:

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(CATEGORY-ID);    
$_categories = $_category->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('url_key','name','image','all_children','is_anchor','description'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
                ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())
                ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
                ->joinUrlRewrite();
```

Note: I have checked that, both of my flat data tables have been successfully populated. This code still works if I change the "Use Flat Catalog Category" option to "No".
Now, what should be the code to get a list of category along with its subcategories where as it may pull data from "catalog_category_flat_store_*" table?

Comment: You don't need to change code if you use flat category table

Comment: And if you load category with its id then you don't need to retrieve collection again you can directly get children with getChildren method

Answer (score 4):

Here I got this code working

```
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(CATEGORY-ID);    
    $_categories = $_category
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image', 'description'))
                    ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren());

    foreach ($_categories as $_category):
       echo $_category->getName();
    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove filters and check.

->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
  ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())

also do a getselect and check what sql query is generated.

Above two will provide further hints.Post those here for further commenting.

Comment: If I simply use:
`
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(CATEGORY-ID);
$_categories = $cat->getChildren();
`
Then I get a string type return data with all its subcategory IDs as comma separated.

Comment: Well Magento does not need a separate code for collection to be pulled from flat category table or from EAV tables.It checks if flat catalog is on will pull from flat catalog tables else from EAV tables